# Sencha app build error

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to build my app with the `sencha app build` command but I get this error :

> [ERROR] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object Stack trace:
>   file:////public/m/app/controller/Nearby.js?_dc=1337687749349 : 62 : App.controller.Nearby#notify

This is my notify() :

```
notify: function(title, message){
  var view = this.getView();

  view.setItems({
    xtype: 'panel',
    html: '<h2>' + title + '</h2><p>' + message + '</p>',
    styleHtmlContent: true
  });
}
```

The view is reference like so

```
refs: { view: 'nearbyview' },
```

And the `App.view.Nearby` has ben added to the required views of another view.

I'm running the last version of the SDK tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found where the problem was coming form.

In a controller, I was using a this route :

```
routes:{
  '':      'home',
}
```

I removed it and everything's working fine now.